# How to reinstall a Windows graphics driver on a Thinkpad T400?

Tags: graphics-card, lenovo-laptop

On my Thinkpad T400, I connected my laptop to a monitor, and then my best Windows graphics driver got unistalled (AMD ATI Radeon HD 3400 Series). I am now stuck with the Mobile Intel(R) 4 series express chipset family which does not perform as well as the original driver. Is it possible to reinstall a graphics driver? I tried to use various software but they don't work.

Comment: Yes; Download the installer from Lenovo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the AMD post
[Driver Support for AMD Radeon™ HD 4000, HD 3000, HD 2000 Series and Older Graphics Products](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-win-legacy):

> Driver support for these products under Windows® 8.1 and Windows® 10 is only available via Windows Update.

If you are on these versions of Windows, just run Windows Update
(*Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update*).

If you are on a previous Windows version, let us know which one.